# In Spark standalone mode, how do I enable JDBC/ODBC access?

Tags: apache-spark

Is it possible to allow JDBC/ODBC access in Spark standalone mode? I know it's possible in YARN mode, but I don't know how to turn it on in standalone mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standalone mode has nothing to do with JDBC connection as long as you have access to your database. The difference between standalone mode and yarn occurs  during the distribution of tasks. In the case of yarn the tasks are distributed along all available nodes through yarn when in standalone mode all tasks will run under one node.